# Rails double render error for multithreading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rspec, rendering

I want to test sign_in in rails from different places at same time, so I use multithreading in rspec:

```
context 'when multiple api calls made at same time' do
  it 'sign_in successfully' do
    request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    threads = []
    10.times do
      threads << Thread.new do
        post :create, user: { email: user.email, password: user.password }
      end
    end

    threads.each do |t|
      t.join
    end
  end
end
```

and the above code has double render error:

```
 AbstractController::DoubleRenderError:
 Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you  
 may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither 
 redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action 
 after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

My controller code:

```
def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name)
  return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
end

def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  resource ||= resource_or_scope
  sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource

  if user_signed_in? && (cannot? :view, :my_app)
    sign_out current_user
    render :status => 401, :json => { :error =>"Access denied." }
  else
    render :json => current_user, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```

The spec works fine for 1.time. Any idea why it complains about double render error for multithreading? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `post` testing method doesn't exercise the entire Rack stack, it just mocks out what's necessary and calls the method on a controller instance.  For this kind of full-stack integration test - you're probably going to want something like Cucumber - which runs the requests in a separate thread from the web server. (And you may want some kind of parallel testing setup to make sure there's more than one server thread at a time.)

That said - I think you're testing libraries and rails in this situation - none of the code YOU wrote here is likely to introduce threading issues, so unless you have reason to believe that Devise and or Rails will fail under the circumstances you're trying to recreate here, I'm not sure the test is really needed.